# Solving Counter Problem in Java Thread With synchronized method and block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I just wrote code for counter problem in a thread. When I add synchronized on Method its working fine but when I use synchronized block inside a method it does not work, why? Something I am missing, I guess.

```
    public class CounterProblem {
    class Counter implements Runnable {
        private Integer count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
//      THIS GIVES 20000 which is correct every time.
        public synchronized void increment() {
            count++;
        }
//      THIS GIVES wrong every time. WHY ?
//      public void increment() {
//          synchronized(count) {
//              count++;
//          }
//      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CounterProblem counterProblem = new CounterProblem();
        Counter counter = counterProblem.new Counter();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(counter);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(counter);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        System.out.println(counter.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass this to synchronized block instead of counter, like synchronized(this) {
             count++;
          }

Comment: synchronized(this) and putting synchronized on method are same so it will work. I want to know why synchronized(count) is not working.

Comment: When you used synchronized(counter), it's only synchronized the block, not whole object, but synchronized method will block whole object. So, when starting another thread, it's reset counter to 0 and then both thread increment the counter.

Comment: Why u need synchronized block in first place? The 2 threads ran independently from each other.

Comment: @AwanBiru They are running independently but both are working on the shared resource.

Comment: Perhaps new Counter for each threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.Integer`'s aren't mutable. When you increment an `Integer`, you unbox it to a primitive `int`, increment it, and then autobox the result to a different `Integer` instance. This means your `synchronized` block synchronizes on a different object every time, making it pointless - as you've seen yourself.

Comment: It should be auto unboxed afaik, not outbox.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala yup, that's correct. Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.